# How do I understand changes across different versions of framework (System.*) NuGet packages?

Tags: .net, nuget-package, .net-standard, system.text.json

I've got a **.NET Framework 4.7.2** application, and am using the .NET CLI tooling and SDK-style projects, and have been happily building my application for some time.

After doing the appropriate performance measuring, I want to bring in `System.Text.Json` to replace a few uses of `Newtonsoft.Json` in one my `netstandard2.0` assemblies. So I [go to NuGet.org and look at the versions available](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Text.Json/), and I see 4.6.0, 4.7.0, 4.7.1, and 4.7.2.

Just "getting the latest" (4.7.2) warns me about upgrading a slew of other packages:

- `System.Buffers.4.4.0 -> System.Buffers.4.5.1`
- `System.Memory.4.5.3 -> System.Memory 4.5.4`
- `System.Numerics.Vectors.4.4.0 -> System.Numerics.Vectors.4.5.0`
- `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.4.5.2 -> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.4.7.1`
- `System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.4.3.0 -> System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.4.5.4`

Even the older 4.6.0 warns me about upgrading *some* of those packages, with (understandably) different target versions:

- `System.Buffers.4.4.0 -> System.Buffers.4.5.0`
- `System.Numerics.Vectors.4.4.0 -> System.Numerics.Vectors.4.5.0`
- `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.4.5.2 -> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.4.6.0`
- `System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.4.3.0 -> System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.4.5.2`

**Where is documentation on the scope of these changes *including dependent packages* to help me choose which version to bring into my application?**

I've looked in [the GitHub repository](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/commits/master/src/libraries/System.Text.Json) for commits that say anything about these package versions (*e.g.* `System.Text.Json.4.7.1`), but haven't found any. I can surmise from the release dates that they're connected to SDK/Runtime releases. For example, 4.7.0 was published on 3-Dec-2019, the release date for .NET Core 3.1; but what about 4.7.1 and 4.7.2? They look likely to be connected with servicing releases, but I'm struggling to find documentation of that.

I'm not targeting .NET Core 3.1 - I'm not targeting.NET Core at all - so "just use the latest and stay up-to-date" isn't a satisfactory answer; I want to understand runtime and API compatibility and be aware of breaking changes, even down the dependency tree. How can I find this information? Is it even available without closely tracking development in the GitHub repository?

Comment: I think, you can start from looking from .net standard compatibility

Comment: Great question, no answers. Me too has a situation where assembly must be ilmerged before deployed and when updating some dependency it suddenly brings in tons of these assemblies for the first time!